# How to get Jersey Web Target from JAX-RS Web Target Decorator?

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-rs, target, payara

After switching from Glassfish Server 5.0.1 to Payara Server 5.191, my websocket cannot be initiated anymore. I get the error

> fish.payara.requesttracing.jaxrs.client.decorators.JaxrsWebTargetDecorator@45>3 is not a valid JerseyWebTarget instance. SseEventSource does not support other WebTarget implementations.

on the build() call.

While debugging I found out that the WebTarget is different when I run the server as a Glassfish comparing to the Payara version.
Here is the Glassfish Web Target:
[image: Glassfish Web Target]

And here is the Payara Web Target:
[image: Payara Web Target]

Does anyone how I get the webtarget of the payara server inside the wt Element to use it for the build function?

Here is some Java code:

```
WebTarget wt =  requestHelper.buildTarget(
            "/events",
            new String[0],
            new Object[0],
            new String[]{"topics"},
            new String[]{String.format("smarthome/%s/%s/%s", "items", itemName, "statechanged")});
    eventSource = SseEventSource
            .target(wt)
            .build();
```